# Array repetitivo

Tags: java

Bom dia galera,

sou novo por aqui e novo também no JAVA. Estou com um problema para tentar solucionar a mesma e não estou conseguindo.

Quando executo o programa, o array dentro do método abrir catalogo se repete inúmeras vezes mesmo eu colocando um parâmetro do arquivo que abri e li o tamanho do .db.

Ao gerar o catálogo em uma função, o catálogo fica enorme sendo que so existem 10 itens dentro.

Poderiam me ajudar?

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class JavaApplication6 {

public static int[] codigo;
public static String[] nome;
public static double[] preco;
public static String[] descricao;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Muito obrigado pelo Acesso! O que deseja fazer primeiro?");
        System.out.println("\n===========================");
        System.out.println("|     1 - Catálogo        |");
        System.out.println("|     2 - Carrinho        |");
        System.out.println("|     3 - Finalizar       |");
        System.out.println("|     4 - Voltar          |");
        System.out.println("|     0 - Sair            |");
        System.out.println("===========================\n");

        int opcao = in.nextInt();
            switch (opcao){
                case 1:
                carregarcatalogo();
                break;
                case 3: 
                finalizarcompra();
            }

}



public static void carregarcatalogo() throws IOException{
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    DataInputStream br = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("produto.db"));

        int tamanho = br.readInt();
        codigo = new int[tamanho];
        nome = new String[tamanho];
        preco = new double[tamanho];
        descricao = new String[tamanho];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        codigo[i] = br.readInt();
        nome[i] = br.readUTF();
        preco[i] = br.readDouble();
        descricao[i] = br.readUTF();

        abrircatalogo(tamanho, codigo, nome, preco, descricao);


}
 }
    public static void abrircatalogo(int tamanho, int[] codigo, String[] nome, double[] preco, String[] descricao){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.printf("+-----+------+------+------+---|\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            System.out.printf("| %06d | %-15s | R$%7.2f | %-35s |\n",
                codigo[i], nome[i], preco[i], descricao[i]);
            System.out.printf("+-----+------+------+------+---|\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Digite o código para selcionar o produto e pressione enter para confirmar");
}

public static void finalizarcompra(){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Para finalizar sua compra, preencha os dados");

    System.out.print("Nome completo que está no Cartão de Crédito: ");
    String cliente = in.next();
    System.out.print("Numero do Cartão de Crédito: ");
    int numCredito = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Data de vencimento: ");
    int vencimento = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("CVV: ");
    int cvv = in.nextInt();
}
}
```

Comment: Dentro do `carregarcatalogo()` tem um `for` que chama o `abrircatalogo()`, que também possui um `for`. Acredito que essa chamada ao `abrircatalogo()` deveria estar fora do `for`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado. Coloquei como resposta pra poder finalizar esta pergunta.

Comment: Sem problemas. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um loop aninhado: o `abrircatalogo()` está dentro de um loop, mas internamente executa outro loop.

Remova o `abrircatalogo()` de dentro do `for`